# Having issue with navigation bar when the screen size is decreasing

Tags: html, css, menu, nav

I have a responsive nav bar. When the screen size decreases a little, the last li goes to the next line under other li's. What should I do to fix it so it doesn't move to the next line under the other menu elements?

HTML codes:

```
<nav class="cd-main-nav-wrapper mainNav">
  <ul class="cd-main-nav">
    <li style="margin-right:none;" class="logoNavPos">
      <a href="index.html">
        <img src="pic/logo1.jpg" alt="" class="desktopLogo">
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="current_page_item">
      <a href="index.html">خانه</a>             </li>
        <li><a href="pages/product.html">مزایای بیمه عمر</a></li>
        <li><a href="pages/ourBranches.html">بیمه عمر و سرمایه گذاری</a></li>
        <li><a href="pages/Catalogue.html">پرسش های متداول</a></li>
        <li><a href="pages/aboutUs.html">درباره ما</a></li>
        <li style="display:none;" class="mobileSwLang">
          <a href="#">English version</a></li>  
    </ul>
  </nav>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/MelodyHajian/4ntL3m9o/
 give me advices plz.

Comment: We will need at least some css to help. Create a jsfiddle with only the needed code to make it work.

Comment: if `li`s are `inline-block`, then `white-space:nowrap;` will do on `ul` else: `ul {display:table} li {display:table-cell;` **float:none** `}` not enough info of yours to make an anwser of this

Comment: @ChrisG I edited the Question, Check the jsfiddle.

Comment: @GCyrillus check the jsfiddle link.

Answer (score 0):

jquery may help
here is a jsfiddle i played with......

```
$(window).resize(function() {
var windowsize = $(window).width();
if (windowsize > 767) {
$('.nav').show();
} else {
$('.nav').hide();
$('.toggle').removeClass('open');
}
})
$('.toggle').click(function(event) {
$(this).toggleClass('open');
if ($(this).hasClass('open')) {
  $('.nav').show();
} else {
$('.nav').hide();
}
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GlynneT/2pv9pkb0/

Comment: i edited the question and added the jsfiddle link.check it out.